# How to apply .each to hide all instances using jquery to find text in a TD

Tags: jquery

I have a jQuery expression that searches for particular text and then wraps it in a div to hide it.

However, the TD contains several instances of this text, and is only recognising the first instance.

I understand that I'd need to use .each to loop through them all, however I'm unsure how to implement this. Unfortunately the text isn't broken up into different classes or ids, which would make things easier.

jQuery:

```
$('td.EventListCalendarItemDefault').html(function (i, t) {
    return t.replace('Apr ', '<span class="hidden">Apr </span>');
})
```

HTML:

```
<td class="EventListCalendarItemDefault" width="33%" height="70" valign="top" style="border-bottom-style:solid;border-bottom-width:1px;">
<a class="yearViewHeader" href="">April</a><br>
<span class="hidden">Apr </span>01 <a href="" title="2019-04-01, 9:00 AM (UTC+11:00)  2019-04-02, 4:00 PM (UTC+11:00)">Hobart</a><br>
Apr 08 <a href="" title="2019-04-08, 9:00 AM (UTC+10:00)  2019-04-09, 4:00 PM (UTC+10:00)">Sydney</a><br>
Apr 11 <a href="" title="2019-04-11, 9:00 AM (UTC+10:00)  2019-04-12, 4:00 PM (UTC+10:00)">Melbourne</a><br>
Apr 15 <a href="" title="2019-04-15, 9:00 AM (UTC+12:00)  2019-04-16, 4:00 PM (UTC+12:00)">Auckland</a>
</td>
```

What could be alternative approach?

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is to use regular exp to select all the occurrences of 'Apr'.

```
new RegExp('Apr ', 'gi')
```

Please see the [JSBin](https://jsbin.com/mowayejaxi/edit?html,js,console,output)

Comment: How can you chain .replace to work with multiple instances? ie. 'Jan ', 'Feb ', 'Mar ' etc., all in different TDs but with the same class.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use below code. It will Resolve your Issue. you have to use case-insensitive replacement like below.

```
var replaceStr = 'Apr ';
$('td.EventListCalendarItemDefault').html(function (i, t) {
    return t.replace(new RegExp("\\b"+replaceStr+"\\b"), '<span class="hidden">Apr </span>');
})
```

Comment: This works, however it removes the 'Apr' in the a tag header, which I need to avoid. I added a space in my original jQuery to get round that, which is missing in the solution.

Comment: @hypertext i have modified answered. For exact match string replacing you have to use regex as i edited in given answered. please check and validate

Comment: Thanks, however currently only the first instance of 'Apr ' is removed, and not the other three.